# Use INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE as a compile-time constant

Tags: c++, winapi, constexpr, reinterpret-cast

`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is defined in WinAPI as follows:

```
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ((HANDLE)(LONG_PTR)-1)
```

On my system that results in:

```
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ((void*)(long long)-1)
```

So I can't use this as a constexpr:

`constexpr auto c = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` gives me an [error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zkjlTq5Tty7GmxoZ):

> cast that performs the conversions of a reinterpret_cast is not allowed in a constant expression

Of course I can use directly `-1` as a value, but is there a way to lean on constant from WinAPI?

The actual code I'm trying to port to different compilers was something with non-type template parameter like this:

```
#define INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ((void*)(long long)-1)

template <void* value>
class C{};

C<INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE> c;
```

This gives me error on clang trunk and gcc 12.2, but compiled well on msvc19 latest and clang 15 ([link to godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KMT6jqf5a)).

Error message for clang says about "constant expression":

> error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

I used `std::intptr_t` now instead of `void*` as a template parameter, but maybe there some other solutions.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is only useful when comparing the return value of a Win32 API call, or when passing it into a Win32 API call. There aren't any Win32 API calls that execute under a `constexpr` context.

Comment: @IInspectable comparing on runtime, but the constant to compare expected to be set on compile-time. See updated post.

Comment: What's the broader picture here? Parameterizing on the `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` value doesn't immediately appear to be useful. After all, it's being used for genuinely invalid `HANDLE`s (e.g. from [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)), but also for valid (pseudo-) handles (such as [`GetCurrentProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocess)). This sounds more like a problem that's more universally solved by parameterizing on a trait object instead.

Comment: @IInspectable it's easier to just have `template<HANDLE invalid_value>` than `template<typename handle_traits>`

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Easier, maybe. But also [wrong](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040302-00/?p=40443). When developers have failed for decades to provide sane abstractions over `HANDLE` values, then maybe the message is to stop trying.

Comment: @IInspectable you missing the point. Type argument is here to actually resolve ambiguity between `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`/`NULL` and usually it's the only handle trait defined in trait class.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` has a value of -1. It cannot ever be confused for a null pointer value by the compiler. Neither at run time nor at compile time.

Comment: @IInspectable my initial comment was answer to yours q: What's the broader picture here? Usual use case is generic RAII wrapper which requires appropriate invalid handle value. Introducing type trait (instead of passing value directly) increases complexity in small one file programs (otherwise I would use WIL).